# python: query a DATETIME field in a sqlite db for a date range

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

Have a sqlite db that I've created in python that has a `DATETIME` field:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('some.db',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Table(...Date DATETIME...)")
    ...
    Date = datetime.datetime(<a format that resolves to the correct datetime object>)
    ...
    altogether = (..., Date, ...)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Table VALUES(...?...)", altogether)
    con.commit()
```

This populates correctly. I later want to be able to query this DB by datetime, and have a function to manage my queries generally:

```
def query_db(path, query, args=(), one=False):
    connection  = sqlite3.connect(path)
    cur = connection.execute(query, args)
    rv = [dict((cur.description[idx][0], value)
               for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv

LOCAL_FOLDER = os.getcwd()
samplequery = "SELECT * FROM Table"
dbFile  = os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, "some.db")
result = query_db(dbFile, samplequery)
```

The above would successfully produce a `result`that gave me everything in the `Table`.

However, how do I structure a query that would, for instance, give me all entries in the `Table` table of `some.db` that have a `Date` within the past 60 days?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
where date >= date('now', '-60 day');
```

EDIT:

Based on your actual query:

```
select <field1>, <field2>, count(1) as num
FROM Table
where date >= date('now', '-60 day');
group by <field1>, <field2>;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is unnecessary when you are using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: So the actual query that we're editing looks as follows:

`select distinct <field1>, <field2>, count(1)  as num FROM Table group by <field1>, <field2>;`.

Where would we add the above query into that if we wanted to filter it by the last 60 days?